# OData Patch not working

Tags: c#, odata, owin

I have an ODataController for more or less simple CRUD functionality. GET, POST and DELETE works fine but PATCH always returns the same error: `'ODataComplexTypeDeserializer' does not support Read.`

This is the `ModelState Error`. My class and method looks like this:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Orders")]
public class OrdersController : CommonODataController
{
    ...
    [HttpPatch]
    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Int64 key, Delta<Order> order)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (order == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Missing order patch information.");
        }
        // do patching stuff
    }
}
```

So when calling PATCH the `ModelState` is invalid and the `order` is `null`.

It cannot be the complexity of `Order` as I already minimized `Order` so that it only contains an `Id`. I also tried it with other entities.

After doing some research I guess that it might have something to do with the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`. The OWIN configuration is:

```
    public void Configuration( IAppBuilder app )
    {
        // create the HttpConfiguration and do not use the GlobalConfiguration with OWIN
        HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfiguration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        app.UseCors( CorsOptions.AllowAll );

        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        // setup dependency injection and register interfaces
        RegisterServices(container);
        RegisterControllers( container );

        // configure JSON formatters
        JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = httpConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        formatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        //formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        formatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        // register routes
        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);          
        ODataConfig.Register( httpConfiguration );

        // setup dependency resolver
        httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseWebApi( httpConfiguration );
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that you want to patch complex type property. However, it's not supported so far in Web API OData. see the related issue:
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/135

Thanks.

Comment: Funny thing is that the PATCH for the order already did work. I think that it broke when we changed some things in the startup configuration.

Comment: :) Patch for entity is originally supported.

Comment: From the question, it sounds like `Order` _is_ an entity, since it has an `Id` property.